# which composer.json executes on composer update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have one questions related to **composer**:
Please look at following directory structure in laravel.

```
laravel
|-- app
|-- bootstrap
|-- config
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
`-- vendor
    |-- composer
    |-- danielstjules
    |   |-- composer.json
    |   `-- and other files
    |-- dnoegel
    |   |-- composer.json
    |   `-- and other files
    |-- doctrine
    |   |-- composer.json
    |   `-- and other files
    `-- doctrine
        |-- composer.json
        `-- and other files
```

and i am using composer to manage dependency.
On my directory structutre, there are *many files* of `composer.json`, mainly in **vendor** folder,in **all sub-folder** of vendor directory has a `composer.json` file.

then my question is :
   if i exceute `composer update` command from my app folder like :

```
vishal@vishal-desktop /var/www/laravel $ composer update
```

1) which `composer.json` will be updated **only of app diectory**? **or**

2) **all composer.json** of all subfolder  in `/var/www/laravel` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer update` in the root folder of laravel is only looking at the `composer.json` in your docroot as well so it knows what dependencies, etc it should look for updates for. The other composer files are for the modules they belong to.

You shouldn't be modifying the vendor folder, either.